# Url que cambia todos los días por fechas?

Tags: url

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenos días tengo la siguiente `url` que cambia todos lo días por motivos de fecha:
https://www.mipaginaweb.es/go.php#!/Employee/2023/05/23/raul-2.html
El caso es que quiero crear un enlace hacia cada perfil, pero al cambiar el parámetro de la `url`, la misma aparece rota al cambiar el día de la fecha.
Se me ha ocurrido realizar algo con una condicional que sea `if then` para cada día, pero tendría que hacerlo manualmente y no se hay otra opción a través de una consulta  de la base de datos.
No se si podrías darme alguna día al respecto?.
Muchas gracias

Muy bien, como me habéis indicado os paso el código:

```
<?php
$today=date(l); 

// Usamos la función date
if($today==Monday){
   echo "<a href='https://www.mipaginaweb.es/go.php#!/Employee/2023/05/23/raul-2.html'>Raul</a>'>";    
}    
elseif($today==Tuesday){
   echo "<a href='https://www.mipaginaweb.es/go.php#!/Employee/2023/05/24/raul-2.html'>Raul</a>'>";    
}    
elseif($today==Wednesday){
   echo "<a href='https://www.mipaginaweb.es/go.php#!/Employee/2023/05/25/raul-2.html'>Raul</a>'>";    
}   
elseif($today==Thursday){
   echo "<a href='https://www.mipaginaweb.es/go.php#!/Employee/2023/05/26/raul-2.html'>Raul</a>'>";    
}    
elseif($today==Friday){    
   echo "<a href='https://www.mipaginaweb.es/go.php#!/Employee/2023/05/27/raul-2.html'>Raul</a>'>";    
}    
elseif($today==Saturday){    
   echo "<a href='https://www.mipaginaweb.es/go.php#!/Employee/2023/05/27/raul-2.html'>Raul</a>'>";    
}    
elseif($today==Sunday){    
   echo "<a href='https://www.mipaginaweb.es/go.php#!/Employee/2023/05/28/raul-2.html'>Raul</a>'>";    
}    
?>
```

Como veréis cambio el parámetro dependiendo del día de la semana, ya que el día de la fecha va cambiando. Es una opción valida pero da mucho trabajo en el sentido que hay que ir modificando esa parte. También se puede crear un `array` por meses, pero igualmente cuando se termine el mes hay que modificar los parámetros.
Veo que salen ocultas las `urls`, me imagino que será por el tema de `spam`, no obstante esta `url` https://www.mipaginaweb.es/go.php#!/Employee/2023/05/26/raul-2.html es cambiar en este caso el día de hoy 26 para al siguiente el 27 y al siguiente el 28 y así sucesivamente...por cada mensaje de cada día de la semana. He sacado una foto al código, espero que se pueda ver bien, porque he tenido que reducir el tamaño.
Alguna idea?
Gracias

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: El date te permite devolver el día actual en el formato que le indiques. En tu caso sería más óptimo que indicaras el formato Y/m/d, de esta manera tendrías la fecha que buscas, y solo tendrías que concatenarla con el enlace  que quieres definir, sin necesidad de esos if